# Convert the Word Document to Binary while it is active

Tags: c#, ms-word, add-in

I need the save a word document to the database. The Problem while doing this is, my document is active hence it cannot be accessed by the add in created.
Here's my code, that need to access the active document!

```
var doc = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
//string FilePath = "C:/Users/karthikeyan.g/Downloads/Top10thingsToCreateFunctions.docx";
string OrgPath = doc.Path;
string FilePath = OrgPath.Replace('\\', '/') + '/' + doc.Name;
//string FilePath = Path.GetTempFileName(); 
      try
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
            string strQuery = "insert into wordFiles(Name,ContentType,Data) values(@Name,@ContentType,@Data)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = doc.Name;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "docx";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;
            br.Close();
            fs.Close();

            if (InsertUpdateData(cmd))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Inserted!");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not Inserted!");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Content of active document cannot be accessed until it is saved. Only way to do that is to access content of it's process.

Comment: But its allowing us to insert some lines to word document?

Comment: Where do you see the error, and what error do you see?

Comment: Actually, my question is to read the content of a word document when it is opened, but in my above program, when i tried to store this in database, it stores 0x0000..... as the binary value i.e. it cant the read the opened document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a duplicate of:
[Serialize current ActiveDocument from office 2007 add-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175273/serialize-current-activedocument-from-office-2007-add-in)

Answer from the MSDN blog: use IPersistFile interface.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranavwagh/archive/2008/04/03/how-to-do-a-save-copy-as-in-word.aspx

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;

var pf = (IPersistFile) Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
pf.Save(@"C:\Temp\hello.doc", false);
```